# Angular: How to access child from the parent. ViewChild, ContentChild none of them are working in specific scenario

Tags: angular, parent-child

I have parent component with the below code

```
<div class="parent">
  parent >>>
  <p>This my parent having child in it</p>
  <div appChildDom >
     <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Child component is defined as below,

```
@Component({
  selector: "div[appChildDom]",
  template: "",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
 })
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor() {}
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      console.log("init child");
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    getContentOfChild() {
      alert('child');
     }
   }
```

In my parent component, im accessing the child using the ViewChild decorator and trying to call the method on the child component.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild(ChildComponent) vchild: ChildComponent;

 constructor() {}
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // this.vchild is always undefined
  alert(this.vchild);
  //  I want to access the child component
  this.vchild.getContentOfChild();
 }
 ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Im able to access the ElementRef but not the childComponent instance.
How to achieve this ? Is this not correct way of defining the parent and child components?
Refer the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vu9dkn?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.ts)

Similar approach works in angular 11.x refer the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/access-element-of-transcluded-compoentn-bgo95r?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

Comment: You can set `static` flag to `false` in `@ViewChild()` decorator like `@ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false})`

Comment: I'm... not quite sure if your `ChildComponent` selector is doing something, it looks more like it should be a directive (which is how you're using it, too).

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Even that didnt help me

Comment: @MikeS. just changed the decorator to Directive. Still it is the same

Comment: @MikeS. This approach works in angular 11.x I had added a link to stackblitz with 11.x version code

Comment: I fixed the issue in the project. The problem is that `ParentComponent` is `standalone` but `ChildComponent` is not. So I converted both components to non-standalone ones. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ms4jyv

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I want it to be standalone component only. Im building with angular 14 standalone components. I do not want to change this just because of this issue

Comment: I had fixed it by importing the childcomponent into the parentcomponent with standalone as true. This worked for me

Comment: @bvakiti Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone who has faced similar issue.
As, it is standalone components. I tried to import the child component inside the parent component and it worked as expected.

[image]